# Как отсортировать div по значению пользователя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется range input, с которого я получаю значение с помощью jquery:

```
<input class="add" type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="10" value="5" />
```

и куча div'ов:

```
    <div class="blocks block-1" id="5">Div 1</div>
    <div class="blocks block-1" id="3">Div 2</div>
    <div class="blocks block-1" id="1">Div 3</div>
    <div class="blocks block-1" id="8">Div 4</div>
    <div class="blocks block-1" id="2">Div 5</div>
```

Как отсортировать дивы по значению c range input ?

Answer (score -1):

собственно все просто

```
var sortedArray = $("div[class^='wrap_']").get().sort(function(a, b) {
   var idx = parseInt($(a).find(".sort_by").val(),10);
   var idx2 = parseInt($(b).find(".sort_by").val(),10);
   return idx > idx2;
});
$(sortedArray).appendTo("body");
```